# How to Add decimal & zero's after number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql

I got a problem with converting values.

My Source values are:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 1 - abcd
- 2 - xyzabcdefgh
- abcdefgh
- lmnop

I need the output as

- 1.00
- 2.00
- 3.00
- 4.00

The problem I have is that some fields contain letters only, and there are also those that contains contain both letters and digits.

I only need to format those numbers only:

- 1                    as                             1.00
- 2                    as                             2.00

The fields containing letters need to remain the same.

Any help please?

Comment: In general, formatting results is better handled in your application code rather than in t-sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
select case 
    when MyVarcharColumn NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' then convert(decimal(18,2), MyVarcharColumn) 
    else MyVarcharColumn 
end as MyVarcharColumn
from x
```

Might not be the most elegent/efficient solution, but it should work

I also Agree with Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Lee said, or enclose within a try catch

```
Declare @str varchar(10)


Set @str = '1'
Begin Try
    Select Convert(Decimal(10,2), @str) -- scale 10, precision 2
End Try
Begin Catch
    Select 'Not Numeric'
End Catch
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
  case when col1 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
     then convert(varchar(50), convert(decimal(18,2), col1)) 
     else col1 end as col1 from mysource
```